# How to cast or convert java.io.File to java.io.List?

Tags: java, list, file

This is what I have so far...

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the name of your file (fileName.dat):");
String fileName = input.nextLine();
points = (List<Point>)new File(fileName);
```

I would like to cast or convert file to list. 
and this is the error message that I get from NetBeans: 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to java.util.List at closestpoints.ClosestPoints.main(ClosestPoints.java:185)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a file to a list, but you can read the contents of the file and parse that as a list. Consider this example code from Alvin Alexander at http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-read-file-java-string-array-list:

```
/**
 *
 Open and read a file, and return the lines in the file as a list
 * of Strings.
 * (Demonstrates Java FileReader, BufferedReader, and Java5.)
 */
private List<String> readFile(String filename)
{
  List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
  try
  {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      records.add(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    return records;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", filename);
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```